# Running Semgrep on Windows and run Pygoat

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd, semgrep

I installed Semgrep on Windows with `pip install semgrep` and it worked. Now, I want to run the entire semgrep registry on pygoat. I downloaded the code from [here](https://github.com/adeyosemanputra/pygoat) and have it in a folder on my laptop. How do you run the registry on this folder? I tried the following:

```
cd semgrep location, then python3 semgrep --config "\pygoat\pygoat"
```

Many other versions of the above as well, but keep getting the following errors.

```
'semgrep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Other errors include 'no such file or directory'.

Answer (score 1):

Try confirming you have Semgrep installed correctly by running --help. It should print to your terminal:

```
$ semgrep --help
```

Then check for Python == where the left and right sides are the same (often a bug):

```
$ semgrep -e '$X == $X' --lang=py path/to/src
```

If the path is the same, navigate to the project folder and try running a simple Semgrep rule from the [Python registry](https://semgrep.dev/r?lang=Python).

If all else, uninstall Semgrep:

```
py -m pip uninstall semgrep
```

Then reinstall:

```
python3 -m pip install semgrep
```

You might need to install Python3 if not already installed on your machine.

Then follow the previous step to confirm you have Semgrep installed.

Answer (score 0):

Semgrep does not work natively on windows, you can either use it via windows subsystem for linux, or run it in a container.

For example:

```bash
wsl --exec sh -c "python3 -m pip install --update semgrep ^&^& semgrep"
```

https://semgrep.dev/docs/getting-started/#installing-and-running-semgrep-locally